# How to read an image from DVR using OpenCV with the resolution you want?

Tags: python, opencv

I have seen several things about capturing frames from an IP webcam stream using python and opencv but how do you capture only one picture at a specified resolution with python and opencv? My cameras are connected to a DVR and have resolution of 1920 x 1080 but when I read the image using:

cv2.VideoCapture('http://admin:admin@192.168.1.20/cgi-bin/net_jpeg.cgi?ch=15')

the image resolution is only 320 x 240.

Any advise on how I can read the image with original resolution of 1920 x 1080? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this-

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("source of video")
cap.set(3, 1920)
cap.set(4, 1080)
```